# Stack corruption "overloaded" struct for std::visit and MSVC debugger

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I was playing around with the code in the [cppreference.com page for std::visit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) and ran into an issue in Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.6 and 15.9.7) debug builds (both x86 and x64, with or without the debugger attached to the process) using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...)->overloaded<Ts...>;

int main()
{
    auto op = overloaded{
        [](int x) { std::cout << "Got int: " << x << '\n'; },
        [](const char* s) { std::cout << "Got cstring: " << s << '\n'; }
    };

    op(4);
    op("Hello");
}
```

On exit of the function, the program fails with the message "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'op' was corrupted."

Release builds do not throw this error, and when I compiled it under g++ and clang++ I did not run into the issue.

I also note that setting up `op` as follows resolves the issue:

```
auto l1 = [](int x) { std::cout << "Got int: " << x << '\n'; };
auto l2 = [](const char* s) { std::cout << "Got cstring: " << s << '\n'; };

auto op = overloaded{l1, l2};
```

Is the first code example resulting in undefined behaviour and/or am I running into a compiler bug?

Comment: File a bug with MSVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this code should work, and I ran into a [Visual Studio bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/346200/runtime-stack-corruption-using-stdvisit.html).